# Perl Script removing words from one file to an output file

Tags: perl, text, split

Im pretty sure this is really basic. However I have no knowledge of Perl and only need to use it this once. So I appreciate your patience.

I am trying to remove unwanted text from a single line below which is in HTML:

```html
    <a target="_blank"          href="http://sharepoint/sites/cerner/quickreferenceguides/Documents/EXP001_Run_Printable_TCI_List.pdf" onmouseover="return overlib('This guide outlines the process for running a printable TCI List', CAPTION, 'TCI LIST');" onmouseout="return nd();">Run Printable TCI List (<i>Revised<i>)</a>
```

All I want to be left with is `Run Printable TCI List (<i>Revised</i>)` which is the text at the end before the `</a>`. I have around 500 of these lines and since they could be changed in the future it makes sense to create a program. Below is my Perl code so far:

```perl
open (SEARK, 'C:\\HTMLsorter\\sources.txt');
open (OUTSEARK, '>C:\\HTMLsorter\\outseark.txt');
while(<SEARK>) {
  chomp;

  if ($_=~/<a target/) {
    $_ =~ s/\<i>//g;
    $_ =~ s/\<\/i>//g;
    @itemsa = split(/>/);
    @itemsb = split(/</, $itemsa[1]);
    print OUTSEARK ("$itemsb[0]\n");
  }
}
close (SEARK);
close (OUTSEARK);
```

I'm sure you can read this but just to explain I am opening a file called `sources.txt` where there are the 500 lines to be sorted. The output file will be `outseark.txt`. So far it will output this:

```
Run Printable TCI List (Revised)
```

This is obviously due to the split aiming at everything in and around the arrows. Any ideas how I keep the italics inside the brackets? To be left with:

```
Run Printable TCI List (<i>Revised<i>)
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When applied to the sample data Your code produces exactly the output you say you require (minus the double-quotes). Is it possible you fixed it yourself by adding `s/\<i>//g` etc. later on?

Comment: Well the issue was that I wanted to leave those <i>'s in as they were there for a reason. Sorry to confuse you as I was tinkering around at this point to check if that indeed was the issue. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I see now why I was misunderstanding your question. The StackOverflow markup was swallowing the HTML tags you used, and they were invisible in the question as it was displayed. Also, the two sample output strings you posted were identical apart from a spurious double quote in one of them. I have edited your post to display what it is I think you intend, and have also added to my answer to provide a new working solution. Please let me know if my assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a proper HTML parser, such as [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder). The code is no more complex as this program demonstrates

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file(*DATA);

print $_->as_text, "\n" for $tree->look_down(_tag => 'a', target => qr/./);

__DATA__
    <a target="_blank"          href="http://sharepoint/sites/cerner/quickreferenceguides/Documents/EXP001_Run_Printable_TCI_List.pdf" onmouseover="return overlib('This guide outlines the process for running a printable TCI List', CAPTION, 'TCI LIST');" onmouseout="return nd();">Run Printable TCI List (<i>Revised<i>)</a>
```

**output**

```
Run Printable TCI List (Revised)
```

---

**Edit**

To use this technique on the files in your example, the code looks like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file('C:\HTMLsorter\sources.txt');

open my $out, '>', 'C:\HTMLsorter\outseark.txt' or die $!;

print $out $_->as_text, "\n" for $tree->look_down(_tag => 'a', target => qr/./);
```

---

**Edit 2**

Now that I understand better what you need I can offer this alternative solution. It uses the [`HTML::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aDOM) module to access the *Document Object Model* of an HTML document, as getting the result you needed with `HTML::TreeBuilder` is relatively difficult.

I've also noticed that your sample HTML contains `<i>Revised<i>` which clearly should be `<i>Revised</i>`, and I have corrected it for this sample test. Regardless, Perl trieds to parse bad HTML as a browser would, and even with the error the output is useable.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::DOM;

my $dom = HTML::DOM->new;
$dom->parse_file('C:\HTMLsorter\sources.txt') or die $!;

open my $out, '>', 'C:\HTMLsorter\outseark.txt' or die $!;
print $out $_->innerHTML, "\n" for grep $_->attr('target'), $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

**output**

(With tags corrected)

```
Run Printable TCI List (<i>Revised</i>)
```

(With original tags)

```
Run Printable TCI List (<i>Revised<i>)</i></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open IFH, '<myfile.txt';
open OFH, '>output.txt';

while (<IFH>) {
  if (/<a\s+target.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/i)
  {
    $_ = $1;
    s/<.*?>//g;
    print OFH "$_\n";
  }
}

close IFH;
close OFH;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer and sorry for the late reply. This helped a lot.

Comment: This is extremely poor practice since it relies on the order of attributes in the HTML. Don't do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in one liner.

```
cat inputfile|perl -ne 'if (s#<a\s+target[^>]+>(.+?)</a>##is){print "$1\n";}'>outputfile
```

It is working:

```
echo '<a target="_blank"          href="http://sharepoint/sites/cerner/quickreferenceguides/Documents/EXP001_Run_Printable_TCI_List.pdf" onmouseover="return overlib('This guide outlines the process for running a printable TCI List', CAPTION, 'TCI LIST');" onmouseout="return nd();">Run Printable TCI List (<i>Revised<i>)</a>
<a target="_blank"          href="http://sharepoint/sites/cerner/quickreferenceguides/Documents/EXP001_Run_Printable_TCI_List.pdf" onmouseover="return overlib('This guide outlines the process for running a printable TCI List', CAPTION, 'TCI LIST');" onmouseout="return nd();">Run Printable TCI List 1(<i>Revised<i>)</a>
<a target="_blank"          href="http://sharepoint/sites/cerner/quickreferenceguides/Documents/EXP001_Run_Printable_TCI_List.pdf" onmouseover="return overlib('This guide outlines the process for running a printable TCI List', CAPTION, 'TCI LIST');" onmouseout="return nd();">Run Printable TCI List 2(<i>Revised<i>)</a>
<a target="_blank"          href="http://sharepoint/sites/cerner/quickreferenceguides/Documents/EXP001_Run_Printable_TCI_List.pdf" onmouseover="return overlib('This guide outlines the process for running a printable TCI List', CAPTION, 'TCI LIST');" onmouseout="return nd();">Run Printable TCI List 3(<i>Revised<i>)</a>'|\
perl -ne 'if (s#<a\s+target[^>]+>(.+?)</a>##is){print "$1\n";}'

Run Printable TCI List (<i>Revised<i>)
Run Printable TCI List 1(<i>Revised<i>)
Run Printable TCI List 2(<i>Revised<i>)
Run Printable TCI List 3(<i>Revised<i>)
```

Comment: The `cat`is a useless, extra process.  Drop it and let Perl read the input file directly: `perl -ne '...' inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: Yes, it is possbile, but I like this way. It show the script ability to be inculded into a pipe. Thanks for the comment.